# Como mostrar fotos do album da camera com o plugin camera cordova?

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova

Tenho um app móvel, o que pretendo saber e fazer é:

Tenho um modal que quando aberto quero que apareçam as fotos que tenho no dispositivo (neste caso no rolo da câmera) e mas mostre numa `div` que já tenho. Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 1):

É possivel acessar as biblioteca de fotos e escolher 1 foto com o plugin de camera do phonegap, mas não listar todas as fotos

O codigo abaixo abre a biblioeteca do celular e permite que voce escolha uma foto, retornando sua localização:

```
var cameraPopoverHandle = navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
popoverOptions: new CameraPopoverOptions(300, 300, 100, 100, Camera.PopoverArrowDirection.ARROW_ANY)
```

});

Comment: Mas eu já vi uma app que lista todas as fotos sem aceder a bibilioteca

Comment: Não é nativa sera?

Comment: Não sei se conheces a zomato e essa a app

Answer (score 0):

Bom tive problema para tentar abrir a galeria ou usar o plugin camera do cordova, o problema não estava relacionando com o plugin da camera, mas com o plugin compat, usando recomendações que encontrei, de forçar sua remoção e instalar a versão 1.1.0.

Para evitar problemas, removi também o plugin da camera, e adicionei novamente.

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera --save

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save

cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat --force --
save

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.1.0 --save
```

Usando o método apresentado por @mauroneto, funcionou perfeitamente.

```
var cameraPopoverHandle = navigator.camera.getPicture(
      function(onSuccess){
        console.log(onSuccess);
      },
      function(onFail){
        console.error(onFail);
      },
      {
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        popoverOptions: new CameraPopoverOptions(
          300, 300, 100, 100, Camera.PopoverArrowDirection.ARROW_ANY
        )
      }
    );
```